# How can I re-raise a Ruby exception in a Rails rescue_from statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit, rescue, rocketpants

My Rails 4 app uses [RocketPants](https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants) for its JSON API and Pundit for authorization.

I have code in my `/app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb` file to handle errors from Pundit. Whenever a user isn't authorized to update a resource, Pundit throws a `NotAuthorizedError` exception and I rescue it with my `user_not_authorized` method:

```
class API::V1::BaseController < RocketPants::Base
  include Pundit
  version 1

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def user_not_authorized
    error! :forbidden
  end

end
```

When I call the `error!` method that [RocketPants provides](https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants#registering--dealing-with-errors) from my exception handler, I expect to get a JSON response like this:

```
{
  "error":             "forbidden",
  "error_description": "The requested action was forbidden."
}
```

Instead, however, calling `error!` just immediately blows up the request:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 143ms

RocketPants::Forbidden - RocketPants::Forbidden:
  rocket_pants (1.13.1) lib/rocket_pants/controller/error_handling.rb:44:in `error!'
  app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb:61:in `user_not_authorized'
```

Full stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/rsobers/17ec2b864c892b5448527d7cbafa79b9).

**Why isn't the `error!` method doing what it should when called from my Pundit exception handler?**

If I put `error! :forbidden` in the middle of my controller action, it works as expected.

For context, the controller that inherits from `base_controller.rb` and calls Pundit's `authorize` method looks like this:

```
class API::V1::MealsController < API::V1::BaseController

  before_filter :find_entity

  def create
    meal = @entity.meals.build(meal_params)

    authorize(@entity, :update?)

    if meal.save
      expose meal, status: :created
    else
      expose meal.errors, status: 422
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently raising exceptions in a `rescue_from` is a bad idea and according to the Rails docs, exceptions raised in a handler are not bubbled up:

> Exceptions raised inside exception handlers are not propagated up.

Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

Instead of re-raising RocketPants' exception, I'm simply creating and returning the JSON error message myself:

```
  def user_not_authorized
    # error! :forbidden
    head 403
    error = { error: 'Action not allowed.', error_description: 'Sorry, you are not allowed to perform this action.'}
    expose error
  end
```

This works!

**UPDATE**

I've since found an even cleaner solution: just **map** the Pundit exception to the RocketPants exception. This means that whenever a `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError` error is raised it'll be treated as a `RocketPants::Forbidden` error.

Got the entire solution down to a single line of code at the top of `base_controller.rb`:

```
  map_error! Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, RocketPants::Forbidden
```

No handler required.